# jQuery Alert Message After Entering Text

Tags: jquery, stored-procedures, asp-classic

`txtTransactionDate` and `txtOperatorNumber` are parameters in a SQL proc, which allow the `cboAssignedSite` drop down to auto populate.  At times, there is no value for `cboAssignedSite` based on the parameters selected, and I want to display a meaningful message to the user indicating this.

What I have attempted thus far is to put an alert inside the change event of one of the text fields. The problem is that the alert appears to happen prior to the form submit, so regardless of whether or not there is a value in the drop down, it always appears empty at the time of the alert.

I am new to jQuery, so it's possible that this isn't even the best way to do this. The goal being to alert the user that the drop down is empty AFTER they have chosen the parameters in the text fields.

Thanks in advance.

Recordset:

```vbs
Set RS= CN.Execute("spSelect @vOperatorNumber = '" & Request.Form("txtOperatorNumber") & "', @vTransDate = '" & Request.Form("txtTransactionDate") & "'")
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('#txtTransactionDate').change
            (
                 function() 
                 {
                    $('#frmRequest').submit();
                 }      
            );

            $('#txtOperatorNumber').change
            (
                 function() 
                 {
                    $('#frmRequest').submit();
                    alert($('#cboAssignedSite option:selected').text());
                }
            );
    });
```

HTML/ASP:

```html
<form name="frmRequest" id="frmRequest" method="post">
    <input name="txtTransactionDate" type="text" id="txtTransactionDate" value="<%=vTransDate%>"/>
    <input name="txtOperatorNumber" type="text" id="txtOperatorNumber" value="<%=vOperatorNumber%>"/>
    <select name="cboAssignedSite" id="cboAssignedSite">
        <%If Not RS.EOF Then
            Do While Not RS.EOF%>
                <option value='<%= RS("assignedSite")%>'
                    <%If Request.Form("cboAssignedSite") = RS("assignedSite") Then Response.Write("selected")%>>
                    <%= RS("location")%></option>
                <%RS.MoveNext
            Loop
        End If%>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Why do you submit the form in jQuery when you change a value? Wouldn't you need both values? You might want to consider checking the values pre-submit on only displaying the message if the drop down is empty: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I do need both values; however, I am not sure how to get both values to the database without submitting the form.  And I have two submits because I am not sure which text field the user will enter first. Again, I'm new the jQuery, so there is probably an easier way.

Comment: No.  I would like to submit the date and operator fields to the database, and then if the drop down menu is empty, tell the user something like "no location is associated with the date and operator you entered."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need/want to prevent the user from submitting the form I would do the following:
add a message div to your html and show it on load, if the drop down is empty:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      if ($('#cboAssignedSite').val() === null) {
        $('#message').show();
      }
    });
  </script>

<form name="frmRequest" id="frmRequest" method="post">
    <div id="message" style="border:1px solid red;display:none">No site available</div>
    <input name="txtTransactionDate" type="text" id="txtTransactionDate" value="<%=vTransDate%>"/>
    <input name="txtOperatorNumber" type="text" id="txtOperatorNumber" value="<%=vOperatorNumber%>"/>
    <select name="cboAssignedSite" id="cboAssignedSite">
        <%If Not RS.EOF Then
            Do While Not RS.EOF%>
                <option value='<%= RS("assignedSite")%>'
                    <%If Request.Form("cboAssignedSite") = RS("assignedSite") Then Response.Write("selected")%>>
                    <%= RS("location")%></option>
                <%RS.MoveNext
            Loop
        End If%>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this without jQuery:

```
<%If RS.EOF and Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then %>
    <div id="message" style="border:1px solid red">No site available</div>
<%end if%>

<form name="frmRequest" id="frmRequest" method="post">
    <input name="txtTransactionDate" type="text" id="txtTransactionDate" value="<%=vTransDate%>"/>
    <input name="txtOperatorNumber" type="text" id="txtOperatorNumber" value="<%=vOperatorNumber%>"/>
    <select name="cboAssignedSite" id="cboAssignedSite">
        <%If Not RS.EOF Then
            Do While Not RS.EOF%>
                <option value='<%= RS("assignedSite")%>'
                    <%If Request.Form("cboAssignedSite") = RS("assignedSite") Then Response.Write("selected")%>>
                    <%= RS("location")%></option>
                <%RS.MoveNext
            Loop
        End If%>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: This also worked. Will have to keep it in my back pocket; I have wanted to do this server side before.  Thanks!